# Is there way to open DEBUG CONSOLE tab after starting debugging with specified preLaunchTask?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code

I have debug configuration with preLaunchTask:

```
{
    "type": "node",
    "request": "launch",
    "name": "index.js - Build then launch",
    "program": "${workspaceRoot}/node/dist/index.js",
    "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}/node",
    "preLaunchTask": "build"
}
```

And when I start debugging, vscode opens OUTPUT tab instead of DEBUG CONSOLE:
[image]

Is there way to open DEBUG CONSOLE after starting debugging? I wanted to create extension with interact with DOM UI, but it turned out that extensions dont have access to DOM UI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `"internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart"` in your launch config to always show the console after starting a debug session.

Answer (score 0):

`"internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart"` is not sufficient for python launch configs.

It also requires

```
"purpose": [
    "debug-test"
],
```

launch.json

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Debug Tests",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "purpose": [ //
                "debug-test"
            ],
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": false,
            "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there way to open DEBUG CONSOLE after starting debugging?

As another alternative, VSCode 1.70 (July 2022) offers:

> ### [Changing Quick Access for Debug Consoles to Debug Sessions](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/153347)

> Quick access menu for debug consoles just lists your debug consoles, but the view menu pretty much lists the same.
>
> **Before**: Quick access for debug consoles:
> [image]
>
> **VScode 1.70**: The quick access should actually just list the debug sessions like the call stack does.
> [image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/31675041/176002619-76133b0e-a520-4e16-ae0d-7809a7474912.png]

See [PR 153727](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/153727), released today in [VSCode insiders](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/).

> This can be accessed with the command Select Debug Session
>
> It would look like this (but as a regular quickpick, not a quick access anymore):
>
> [image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/31675041/180053552-b01a574c-34a6-4e2a-bef8-369e6d560f41.png]
>
> for this tree structure:
> [image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/31675041/179634597-b10ed6a8-6ee4-43d6-959c-55e47475c4f2.png]
>
> Or for something different like python (where there are no compact debug sessions):
> [image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/31675041/180053733-83b54f44-3063-4884-b70f-71332bee24ae.png]
>
> tree structure:
> [image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/31675041/180053775-7d090f29-d779-457e-a432-1cc05352e92a.png]
>
> The structure is pretty generic to support any type of debug session.